# Regex Split String

Tags: php, regex, split

I'm using the first time regex and I want to split a string in three vars

```
Target: '[|'.$1.'||'.$2.'||'.$3.'|]'; //each single var.
```

what I have:

```
preg_match_all("[|(.*)||(.*)||(.*)|]", $loadedList, $result);
```

I'm really getting crazy, therfore your help is more than wellcome ;-)
regards Simon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this? It will work for a variable amout of items.

```
$result = explode('||', preg_replace('/(^\[\||\|\]$)/', '', $loadedList));
```

Comment: your answer is what i searched. sexy and sophisticated. thumbs up!

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the special characters:

```
preg_match_all("/\[\|(.*)\|\|(.*)\|\|(.*)\|\]/", $loadedList, $result);
```

Answer (score 0):

`|` is a metacharacter in regular expressions (meaning "or"), so it needs to be escaped if meant to match literally. Furthermore, `[...]` is regex syntax for a character class, meaning "any one of the characters between `[...]`). And finally, you need delimiters around your regular expression.

You could try

```
preg_match_all("/[^\[\]\|]+/")
```

to match all non-`|`/`[`/`]`  strings, i. e. everything except `|`, `[` or `]`.

Comment: He did want exactly three matches though, but this is a good general case.